# Android - DialogFragment not Showing

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment

I wanted to display a dialog by the time I press back button but the code below does not execute and display the FragmentDialog. Thanks in advance.

```
  //BackPress
      public void onBackPressed() {

          TestDialogFragment test= new TestDialogFragment();
          test.newInstace();
            // Showing Alert Message

          Log.d("Video Backpressed", "sdfdf");
      }
```

**TestDialogFragment**

```
public static class TestDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static DialogFragment newInstace() {
        DialogFragment dialogFragment = new TestDialogFragment();
        return dialogFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("TestDialogFragment");
        builder.setView(getContentView());
        Dialog dialog = builder.create();
        return dialog;
    }

    private View getContentView() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment, null);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't call `show()` method of `DialogFragment`. On your code you only created an instance of `DialogFragment`.

```
public void onBackPressed() {

    TestDialogFragment test= new TestDialogFragment();
    test.show(getFragmentManager(), "my_dialog");

}
```

Comment: Getting error sir, "The method show(FragmentManager, String) in the type DialogFragment is not applicable for the arguments (FragmentManager, String)"

Comment: Are you using `FragmentActivity`? Then use `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: Yes, I am using FragmentActivity, and it is working now. Can you put a brief explanation about your answer. Then I will accept your resolve. Thank you for the response. Good Day!